# Is the auto-renewable In-App-Purchase price per period or per month?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, itunes-store

Is the auto-renewable In-App-Purchase price tier set in iTunes Connect per subscription period or per month?

E.g. An IAP with `subscription period` 3 months and `price tier` 99ct, does it charge 99ct every month or 99ct for 3 months?

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html) say:

> Price Tier: The price tier at which you want to sell the subscription
>   for this duration.

Since there is also a 7 day subscription period I would assume that the price is for the period. On the other hand all other periods are multiples of 1 month.

Comment: "The price tier at which you want to sell the subscription for **this duration**" - so, it is for the period, 7 days, 1 month, 12 months or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give **3 Month** as time period they will charge you every 3 month.

Based on your Example query they charge 99ct for 3 months

[**Go through this Link**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html) and [**Go through this Link**](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf)